# Persisting data in a Razor Partial View

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, partial-views, razor-pages

I am using **ASP.NET Core 2.0** and **Visual Studio 2017**.

I want to create a **Razor** partial view to display the menu of our application. The menu is created dynamically as each user will only have menu items for which they have the necessary permissions (so the menu will be different for each user).

The problem I'm having is persisting the menu in the **Razor** partial view. There is no **PageModel** code-behind in a **Razor** partial view, so the problem I'm having is that the menu disappears when you click onto another page. I've persisted the menu in session storage, but I can't figure out how to load the menu from session storage into the Razor partial view.

I've tried loading the session storage menu into **ViewData** but this is wiped out when you click on another page.

How do I persist data in my **Razor** partial views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using partial view, consider using a view component.

```
public class MenuComponent : ViewComponent
{
    SomeDependency userDetails;

    public MenuComponent(SomeDependency userDetails)
    {
      //store this userDetails data to extract profile info in Invoke method
      this.userDetails = userDetails;
    }

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke() 
    {
       //check for logged in  user profile here and return appropriate view
       return View(viewName,ModelObjectForView);
    }
}
```

**1.Create required menu views**

Create the appropriate views for displaying menu for each role or use 
 conditional rendering.
 Please note view for view components will be looked in to 
 /Views/ControllerName/Components/ViewComponentName/ViewName.cshtml this 
 location instead of /Views/ControllerName/ViewName.cshtml.

**2.Define Layout Page**

Now, since you need to display menu for all the pages user navigates to, you 
 need to extract this view component in a layout page. Create a **_Layout.cshthml** 
 file and make sure views that need to show menu item uses this layout page.
 In the _Layout.cshtml , you can now **render the view component** defined above by calling

`@await Component.InvokeAsync(nameof(MenuComponent))`

**3.Using ViewComponent instead of PartialView**

I am suggesting use of ViewComponent over PartialView in this case because 
 ViewComponent will allow you to have its own model (RoleDetails for user in 
 your case) in comparison to PartialView 
 where you will have to pass some child data from view model and hence will have 
 to keep that data in each of your view model. Otherwise , you can even use PartialView. The important thing here is layout page that will help you keep menu across all views presented to user.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I'll give that a try and see if it helps.

Comment: Having read around ViewComponents I think it is definitely the correct approach. I will mark this as answer. Many thanks for your solution I appreciate it :)